# Why code snippet in VB is more featured than in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, msdn

As I read 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx:

For VB:

> Inside the Snippet element, add the
>   References element and all of the
>   required child elements that add a
>   reference to the project when the
>   snippet is inserted.

For C#

> Visual C# code snippets to do not
>   support the References section, so a
>   reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   must be added to the project manually

What fundamental reason prevents C# to support References like VB ?

Update: I saw this posted http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dc06b54c-b6c4-4cf5-8203-a09c6979e881

But it isn't even as full-featured as Code Snippet References as Code Snippet References will allow you to add multiple references at once not just one by one.

C# is supposedly more "professional" than VB.NET, one would expect C# to be more featured not more limited or does "professional" means you have to do it the hard way as said "MANUALLY" :p

When will the C# team catch up with VB.NET team ?

Comment: Ooh, interesting. If this worked I could have all my favourite references just as snippets ;)

Comment: Because the VB team included this feature and the others didn't, probably

Comment: @Marc: You might be interested in http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dc06b54c-b6c4-4cf5-8203-a09c6979e881 and http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e8123d4c-e4dd-4d11-8fc0-fbe6c6382e8f.

Comment: @Nicole Interesting but poorer than VB.NET code snippet add references.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Karen Liu of the C# IDE team responded to this in a [feedback report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91062/need-references-element-to-be-supported-in-c-snippets):

> Thanks for submitting this suggestion.
>   This is something we are aware of and
>   had tried to do as a Design Change
>   Request before. Ultimately, based on
>   cost to implement this where we were
>   in the product cycle, we made the
>   tough decision that since references
>   would be something you would need to
>   add only once, this did not make it
>   into VS2005. This is something we are
>   looking to do in the future though and
>   hearing feedback on this is valuable.

Only nine upvotes, not enough to make it a popular request.  I'd recommend you vote it up, they *do* pay attention to that.

Comment: Interesting but this report concerns add reference NOT code snippet per because for code snippet why on earth can't they use the same code implementation for C# and VB.NET since it is almost the same thing ?

Comment: The VB.NET and C# IDEs only look the same.  Very distinct chunks of code under the hood.  And separate teams to support and develop it.  Small teams is a survival strategy for a company like Microsoft, big ones don't work.

Comment: C# is supposedly more "professional" than VB.NET, one would expect C# to be more featured not more limited or does "professional" means you have to do it the hard way as said "MANUALLY" :p

Comment: That's an incredibly loaded term, professional programmers have no trouble writing solid code in VB.NET.  But Visual Basic has had a very strong IDE for well over 20 years now.  It does stand to reason that it gets a bit more attention within the team and that it took the C# team a while to catch up to this much history.

Comment: Good answer that's it for me the C# team has to catch up with the VB.NET team.

Answer (score 11):

The fundamental reason is that VB thought the scenario had more value for their customers than C# did and hence invested in the feature.  There is nothing preventing C# from adding the feature.  It simply didn't meet the cut list when they evaluated it against other IDE fetaures.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't for allowing business partners to make money developping third parties addins.

Comment: Why the C# team cannot use the VB.net source code for snippet since it's almost the same thing ?

Comment: @user310291 no it has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: @user310291 the VB and C# sources are different and features cannot be simply ported directly between them.

Comment: @JaredPar why MS is proposing this poor alternative http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dc06b54c-b6c4-4cf5-8203-a09c6979e881 instead of proposing the equivalent full-featured as for VB.NET ?

Comment: @user310291 a non-microsoft employee posting an addin to the gallery is not MS proposing an alternative.

Comment: OK then when will the C# team catch up with VB.NET team ?

Answer (score 1):

politician reasons, IMHO C# is more "hardcore", while vb is more "let's do it quick and contract a codemonkey to do it.

So, a VB programmer usually will stick with a standard (vanilla install) visual studio installation, while a c# programmer will install one (or more) plugins (Resharper,Coderush,etc.) , not counting extra components (Telerik, Devexpress..), instead a c# will not work unless visual studio have at least one extra code assistance plugins.

Comment: Plugins had nothing to do with the decision.

Comment: Why not?. In fact, there are more plugins supporting c# than vb.net and almost every plugins is tenfold times better than the visual studio alternative.

Comment: @malleganes, teh amount of plugins just didn't factor in.  It's the VB team sitting in a room looking at a feature list and saying "this will be valuable to customers given the cost and doesn't force us to not implement a feature we think is more valuable".  The C# sat in a room and didn't think the same thing.

Comment: it would not be politically correct for MS to answer that plugins have anything to do ;)