# VS 2010 Code Snippets - C# equivalent of <Imports>?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

Is it possible for a C# code snippet to add lines to the "using" block at the top of a .cs file?  I see the  element for VB but that doesn't work in C#.

Comment: FYI: `Alt+Shift+F10` will show the smart-tag drop down to insert missing `using`s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why code snippet in VB is more featured than in C# ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473600/why-code-snippet-in-vb-is-more-featured-than-in-c)

Comment: This doesn't get done until there are enough votes.  This ought to be done, important to make snippets useful.  Be sure to vote, if you like snippets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171432.aspx):

> The Imports element is only supported for Visual Basic projects.

There is no equivalent for C#